# Clarification on code regarding compilers Order of Evaluation

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, operator-precedence

From the information online I have gathered that order of evaluation is evaluating the left side of the operand before the right. However when looking online this is also similar to short circuiting, as that is also evaluating the left before the right. Below my code represents short circuiting however would like it to show order of evaluation. Would anyone know what would need to be changed within the code below to show the code in terms of order of evaluation as opposed to what its currently being shown as a short circuit when running within my compiler. Compiler uses Minijava.

```
class ImpFact{
    public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(new Fac().ComputeFac(10));
    }
}

class Fac {

    public int ComputeFac(int num){
    boolean a;
    boolean b;
    int result;

    a = false;
    b = false;

    if (a || b) {
    result = 3;
    }
    else {
    result = 7;
}
    return result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand what you are expecting as a response to the question.

But it's easy to characterise the difference between short-circuit evaluation and strict order of evaluation.

Consider the statement:

```
b = f(a) + g(a)
```

In a language which guarantees strict left-to-right evaluation order (such as Java), then function `f` will be called before the function `g`, but *both functions will always be called.

On the other hand, with the expression

```
b = f(a) || g(a)
```

`f` will be called first, but it is quite possible that `g` will not be called. The evaluation can stop after `f` returns, if it returns a true value.

There are also languages, like C, that don't guarantee left-to-right evaluation. In those languages, when `f(a) + g(a)` is evaluated, it is possible that `g` is called before `f`. But short-circuit evaluation (with boolean operators) works the same because short-circuit evaluation must be strictly ordered.

Comment: In terms of the java code given within the question how would it be changed to show order of evaluation as currently it is showing short circuiting?

Comment: @RyanReynolds: how is it currently showing short-circuiting?

Comment: As from my knowledge short circuit is when the left side of the operator is evaluated before the right. Therefore as A is false then B must be false, but now thinking about it would an && expression instead be used?

Comment: @RyanReynolds: short circuit evaluation is when the evaluation of the left hand argument can result in the right-hand argument not being evaluated. Eg. `if (a == 0 || b / a > 0.5) ...`. That expression is safe because of short-circuit evaluation. If `a`  is 0, `b/a` must not be evaluated.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an edit to the code within the question using the information given. Unsure on how to implement the if statement when both a and b are boolean types.

Comment: @ryan: it's pretty common for compilers to rewrite boolean expressions as `if` statements. It's not a complicated transformation. Don't you have some kind of textbook?

Comment: issue is not that I dont understand what is meant by the answer but instead my compiler only accepts a and b as type boolean. When parsing the if statement given in your answer recieve errors.

Comment: @ryan: it is hard to show the effects of short-circuit evaluation when neither argument of the boolean operator requires evaluation. You could see it in the generated code, maybe: the variable `b` would not be examined of `a` were `true`. But that's not going to have a visible execution effect.

Comment: Oh I see so make A true and B false thus utilising short circuit evaluation as the left operand is true as B would not be evaluated by the compiler.